# Regex to replace all ocurrences of a given character, ONLY after a given match

Tags: regex, perl, replace

For the sake of simplicity, let's say that we have input strings with this format:

```
*text1*|*text2*
```

So, I want to leave *text1* alone, and remove all spaces in *text2*.

This could be easy if we didn't have *text1*, a simple search and replace like this one would do:

```
%s/\s//g
```

but in this context I don't know what to do.

I tried with something like:

```
%s/\(.*|\S*\).\(.*\)/\1\2/g
```

which works, but removing only the first character, I mean, this should be run on the same line one time for each offending space.

So, a preferred restriction, is to **solve this with only one search and replace**. And, although I used Vim syntax, use the regular expression flavor you're most comfortable with to answer, I mean, maybe you need some functionality only offered by Perl.

**Edit:** 
My solution for Vim:

```
%s:\(|.*\)\@<=\s::g
```

Comment: `awk` can solve this problem for you in no time.

Comment: You mean, first parsing the "column" through awk, and then using sed or whatever to run the search and replace in only that column?

That's similar to my actual solution, but I would like to do it only with the regex.

Comment: @Carl Norum: I installed awk, but it just sits there and does nothing.  Or did you mean an awk program? :)

Comment: +1 @ysth, thanks =)  you just made a hellish debugging session turn happy here.

Comment: @Doppelganger, `awk` can do the search and replace too.  Why bother using a complicated regular expression when you can use a tool that makes what you're trying to do clearer (and is easier to boot)?

Comment: @Carl Norum Well, now I'm just sure that it's possible, and trying to figure out how to do it (I mean, the final goal is enlightenment). Then I'll see if it's the optimal solution.

Comment: No single operation solution is going to be optimal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way, in perl:

```
s/(^.*\||(?=\s))\s*/$1/g
```

Certainly much greater efficiency is possible if you allow more than just one search and replace.

Comment: I'm currently reading this answer to a similar question that I found only after asking mine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608319/regex-replace-but-only-between-two-patterns

The accepted response uses lookaround to, so maybe yours is similar. I haven't grokked lookaround yet, so I'll try to understand your solution and see if it works.

Comment: @Doppelganger: The lookaround isn't actually necessary in mine; `s/(^.*\||)\s*/$1/g` should work just as well.  I was thinking the lookforward would make it some faster, but don't know if that's true.

Comment: I found my solution with lookaround, but I'm still trying to understand yours. I don't get this atom (^.*\||), i get it as anything from beginning of line until a pipe, but I don't understand what the second pipe is for.

Comment: The second pipe means "or nothing".  After the first time, the capturing group matches the empty string before each character.  If the `\s*` matches any spaces, they get discarded because they're not included in the group.  Success with regexes is all about thinking outside the box. ;)

Answer (score 3):

So you have a string with one pipe (`|`) in it, and you want to replace only those spaces that don't precede the pipe?

```
s/\s+(?![^|]*\|)//g
```

Comment: Better than mine.  Or `s/\s+(?!.*?\|)//gs`

Answer (score 0):

You might try embedding Perl code in a regular expression (using the `(?{...})` syntax), which is, however, rather an experimental feature and might not work or even be available in your scenario.

This

```
s/(.*?\|)(.*)(?{ $x = $2; $x =~ s:\s::g })/$1$x/
```

should theoretically work, but I got an "Out of memory!" failure, which can be fixed by replacing '\s' with a space:

```
s/(.*?\|)(.*)(?{ $x = $2; $x =~ s: ::g })/$1$x/
```

Comment: If you are doing multiple substitutions, might as well do `s/(\|.*)/(my$x=$1)=~s!\s!!g;$x/se`; no `(?{...})` needed.